# Load xml file into 2d rectangular array using linq

Tags: c#, xml, arrays, linq

I'm currently using a jagged array : `private double[][] array;` and I load the array like so.

***Loading the jagged array***

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("file.Xml");
array = doc.Root.Elements("Month").Select(month => month.Elements().Select(x => (double)x).ToArray()).ToArray();
```

So now my problem is I need to get the lenght of the inner array and as I readed it's not possible, so I would need to load the xml in a rectangular array `private double[,] array;` but with linq I don't know how.

***XML looks***

```
<document>
  <Month>
    <Depth>-0.25</Depth>
    <October>0.95</October>
    <November>-0.90</November>
    ...
  </Month>
  <Month>
    <Depth>-0.5</Depth>
    <October>0.47</October>
    <November>-0.17</November>
    ...
  </Month>
  ...
</document>
```

Comment: Why it's not possible to get length of inner array?

Comment: Is Linq a requirement?

Comment: Well I get an exception when I try getLenght(1), and I,ve readed here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2457507/how-do-i-get-the-inner-arrays-length-in-a-2d-array-in-c I think it's the last post

Comment: @C.Evenhuis well it need to be fast, since it's in an event, and I know linq do a good job, but no, it's not a requirement

Comment: there's no need to store it in an array

Comment: @Mokmeuh Linq doesn't run faster than regular code, it just allows short, readable code instead of large nested loop blocks. It's primarily based on one-dimensional sequences (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7318931/array-operations-with-n-dimensional-array-using-linq-c)

Comment: @C.Evenhuis As I said, it's not an obligation to use linq because the array is loaded only when user click on a specific place and is loaded the first time the user start the application, but the link you gave me, would be a solution to my problem, or to support your explication ?

Comment: @Mokmeuh the link informs about how Linq and rectangular arrays don't mix together intuitively. Your question directed towards Linq, that's why I commented. If you decide not to use jagged arrays you could give plain old C# a go yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
double[][] array = 
   doc.Root.Elements("Month")
      .Select(month => month.Elements().Select(x => (double)x).ToArray())
      .ToArray();

foreach(var innerArray in array)
    Console.WriteLine(innerArray.Length); // you can get length of inner array
```

Comment: I can't permit to do a foreach since it would be called on mousemove and it would constantly get called if the suer move in the canva

Comment: @Mokmeuh sorry didn't get you. Can you explain what's wrong with *foreach*? And what exactly you want to get from `array`?

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear, let me try again, what I meant is, the foreach would be called every time the mouse mouve so it would take alot of ressources, and the lenght is needed in a ternary conditional like so,
`array[yCurrent >= array.GetLength(1) ? 11 : yCurrent][xCurrent >= array.GetLength(0) ? 12 : xCurrent]` but I can't get the lenght of the dimmension 1 since it doesn't exist because it's not a rectangular array

Comment: @Mokmeuh you are not forced to enumerate `array`. That was just an example of accessing inner array length. You can do same via accessing by index `array[0].Length` - that will give you length of first inner array

Comment: .... I'm dumb xD, let me try this, and it's working, alright, thank you, I guess I was asking the wrong question